# Universally repelling and universally attracting objects are equivalent?

Tags: category-theory

In Lang’s algebra book, he defines two things.

An object $P$ is called universally attracting if there exists a unique morphism of each object into $P$, and is called universally repelling if for each object, there exists a unique morphism of $P$ into this object. When context makes our meaning clear, we shall objects as above ‘universal’.

Also, he wrote that it is clear that if $P$, $P’$ are two universal objects, then there exists a unique isomorphism between them.

I tried to prove this statement but it wasn’t clear to me.

I’m struggling with the case when $P$ is universally repelling and $P’$ is universally attracting. I think it suffices to show there exists a morphism from $P’$ into $P$.

In the definition of a category, there’s no statement such as [for an ordered pair of objects, there exists at least one a morphism between them]. So in my opinion, it’s possible that there exists a category such that for some pair of objects ($A$, $B$), $Mor(A,B)$ is empty.

How can I prove two universal objects have an isomorphism between them?

Thank you.

Comment: What's probably meant is only when you have two attracting or two repelling, not one of each. For example, the empty set is repelling and any singleton set is attracting in the category of sets, but they aren't isomorphic.

Comment: By the way, the more common terminology for these is "initial" for universally repelling and "terminal" for universally attracting.

Comment: @SCappella Ohhh thank you!! And that terminology is more intuitive..! I will keep it in mind l.

Answer (score 1):

As SCappella comments, only for any two universal objects $P,P'$ of the *same type* (repelling / attracting) there exists a unique isomorphism between them.

If one of $P, P'$ is universally repelling and the other is universally attracting, this is in general not true. In fact, if $P$ is universally repelling and $P'$ is universally attracting, then there exists a unique morphism $\phi : P \to P'$. But there is no reason why $\phi$ should be an isomorphism in *any category*.

As an example take the category of sets and functions: All one-point sets are universally attracting, but only  the empty set is universally repelling.