# Tensor product as universal object: a question arising from Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am reading Lang's Algebra, especially Tensor product, which he defines as follows:

> Let $R$ be a ring, and $M_1,\ldots,M_n,F$ be $R$-modules. A map $f:M_1\times \cdots \times M_n\rightarrow F$ is multilinear if it is $R$-linear in each variable/component $M_i$. One may view the multilinear maps of a fixed set of modules $M_1,\ldots,M_n$ as the objects of a category: if $f:M_1\times \cdots \times M_n\rightarrow F$ and $g:M_1\times \cdots \times M_n\rightarrow G$ are multilinear, we define a morphism $f\rightarrow g$ to be a homomorphism $h:F\rightarrow G$ such that $g=h\circ f$ (first apply $f$, then $h$). A universal object in this category is called a Tensor product of $M_1,\ldots,M_n$.

**My Question:** In what sense should one think tensor product as universal? More precisely, is it universally attracting or repelling?

*Why question came to mind?:* After mentioning about tensor product as **a universal object**, I went to see the definition he gave. He defined universally attracting and repelling objects in a Category, and said,

*When the context makes our meaning clear, we shall call universally attracting or repelling objects as **universal**.*

Therefore, I asked myself:

> for the category of multilinear maps from a fixed set of $n$ modules over $R$, how should we take the universal object? If only universally attracting object exists in this category, why universally repelling does not exist (or vice versa)?

Comment: The tensor product is meant to be the initial object in this category.

Comment: Why we should not consider terminal object in such category?

Comment: Initial and terminal aren't really inherently different. Just take the opposite category. The tensor product is sort of frustrating categorically since it is not in generally a product or coproduct.

Comment: The category you describe is the so called 'under category' of the product of the $M_i$ and R-modules, and as such inherits all limits from R-Mod (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/under+category,). Thus the terminal object - as it is a limit - would not be that interesting.

Comment: I never studied category theory, but from the standpoint of linear algebra, a tensor generalises every object one could encounter in this field: scalar, vector, linear map, linear form, inner product, etc. So, calling a tensor a _universal object_ still makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Maxence1402 This understanding of yours is partial and, in this context, misleading.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path It can be partial, but could you please point out the place?

Comment: @MathsRahul In the language of category theory an object is not called "universal" because it generalizes certain down-to-earth constructions, but because it satisfies properties of existence and/or uniqueness of morphisms relatively all other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the tensor product is universally repelling (or, as S.Farr comments, an *initial object*). Your category also has a universally attracting (or *terminal*) object. This is the map $0 : M_1\times \cdots \times M_n\rightarrow 0$ to the trivial $R$-module $0$. As you see, this is not very interesting.

It also shows that initial and terminal objects, if they exist in a category, are not necessarily isomorphic. See also [Universally repelling and universally attracting objects are equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609136)